# How to make a php cronjob under Debian

Tags: php, linux, cron, debian

I'm trying to set a cronjob to run every 20 minutes.
The file path is /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php

but i need to transfer to it a var so basically to cron:
/srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php?db=LONDON

I tried to use "crontab -e" and set it even to every minute with:

```
 * * * * * /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php?db=LONDON
```

it saved it to /tmp/crontab.something/crontab

And it doesn't seem to work.
I'm new to linux please help.

Comment: for a start you need to add php, either just php <path to file> or the full php path depending on config

Comment: add MAILTO="" at the top of the crontab file with your address, it will email you if there's a problem, great for testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, when calling a PHP script from the command line, you will **not pass it parameters the way you did here**.

You'll typically pass those like this :

```
/srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php db=LONDON
```

And, from your PHP script, you will not get the data into `$_GET`, but into **`$_SERVER['argv']`**

For example, if I create a `temp.php` script that contains this :

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER['argv']);
```

Calling it this way :

```
php temp.php db=LONDON
```

will get me the following output :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "temp.php"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "db=LONDON"
}
```

Then, note you should probably **call the `php` executable program**, from your crontab, and not directly the PHP script -- unless you made it executable.

Which probably means using something like this :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php db=LONDON
```

Note : you may need to adapt the path to `php`.

Answer (score 3):

Call it with php:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php?db=LONDON
```

For the db=LONDON part, you may need to just pass LONDON as a command line arg.  See the following site for more details on that:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Answer (score 0):

See Pascals response re: variables.

For every 20 minutes you want:

```
*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_Xml.php db=LONDON
```

Which says to run the script whenever the minutes is divisible by 20.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 additional options you could consider.

For a PHP script which you intend using from the command-line, you can use the PEAR [Console_Getopt](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Getopt) command-line option parser which offers similar functionality to getopt libraries for other languages.

If your PHP script needs to run in a web context, you can use a cron job to make requests for the URL. A [stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php) covers this.