# Using WGET to run a cronjob PHP

Tags: php, linux, cron, wget

I tried to do a cron and run a url every 5 mintues.

I tried to use WGET however I dont want to download the files on the server, all I want is just to run it.

This is what I used (crontab):

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://www.example.com/cronit.php
```

Is there any other command to use other than wget to just run the url and not downlaod it?

Comment: Probably too late, but you could use curl, the default operation mode doesn't download, but is not always present on the servers.

Comment: Yeah, curl definitely seems like a better solution than using wget.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You could tell wget to not download the contents in a couple of different ways:

```
wget --spider http://www.example.com/cronit.php
```

which will just perform a HEAD request but probably do what you want

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/cronit.php
```

which will save the output to /dev/null (a black hole)

You might want to look at wget's -q switch too which prevents it from creating output

I think that the best option would probably be:

```
wget -q --spider http://www.example.com/cronit.php
```

that's unless you have some special logic checking the HTTP method used to request the page

Comment: `wget --quiet --spider --timeout=0 --tries=1 "http://www.example.com/cronit.php"` - this is what I'm using to "ping" a long running php script... *disclaimer* I don't have much experience with `wget` or `crontab` so read the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) and test the solution in your own environment.

Comment: I found that if I use the `-q` option, the script (on my server) is not executed, so I leave that out. When I run the script in the terminal, I see output, but does that result in problems when it's run in a cronjob? I guess not, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 19):

```
wget -O- http://www.example.com/cronit.php >> /dev/null
```

This means *send the file to stdout, and send stdout to /dev/null*

Answer (score 5):

I tried following format, working fine

```
*/5 * * * * wget --quiet -O /dev/null http://localhost/cron.php
```

Comment: Works for me, too, but a bit confused how `--quiet` and `-O` co-exist.

Answer (score 4):

If you want get output only when php fail:

```
*/5 * * * * php -r 'echo file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/cronit.php);'
```

Or more secure:

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/example/cronit.php
```

This way you receive an email from cronjob only when the script fails and not whenever the php is called.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use this code to hit the script using cron job using cpanel:

```
wget https://www.example.co.uk/unique-code
```