# Regularly performed script

Tags: php

I am wondering if the following can be accomplished with PHP. Lets say that you have simple scripts which only insert some records into database (lets say some reporting) e.g. money incomes/withdraws.

And every 13th day in a month, you have some regular payment for electricity, mortgage etc. Is it possible, that PHP on 13th day every month at 00:00:01 AM perform some insert action.

In addition, is it possible that this is performed without even logging/using the application (without user interaction)? Is there a way how ensure that such action will be definately performed only once a month?

Thank you

Comment: use cron or cron simulation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: the standard way to do this is a cron job

Comment: in PHP, `sleep(1123201);`... Nah just kidding, use a CronJob that runs at the specified date which will either call a PHP script you prepared for it, or any other kind of script for that matter...

Comment: If you really want a PHP solution, try this: `while (true) { sleep(2592000); do_function(); }` ;)

Comment: @Matthew, that would be run at 00:00:00 not 00:00:01 as he asked...

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
They are independent of any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a cronjob. You can find more information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php).

Comment: OK, but what i found on my hosting provider is to set some http://www.domain.eu/script.php url to be triggered at specific time. But what in case that somebody finds out this url and than corrupt my register by repeatedly executing it.

Is there a way how to block such URL and allows only the cron to triggered it?

In addition, is there a way how such CRON expression incoporate to the PHP script to be independent form hosting provider?

Comment: You could set a GET variable that contains a secret password that only you know about and is hard to guess, or restrict access by a certain IP. But these are just minor roadblocks as both of these could be spoofed/guessed. There isn't really a way to protect these pages. Additionally, cron expressions are standard and should work everywhere.

Comment: script outside the root, problem solved

Comment: Could you please more specify it? Like using some middle folder in the structure will make the URL unable to be guess?