# Php crontab function call

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have written a crontab to call a function with following syntax to run every 5 minutes,

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://localhost/domain/path/front_orders/recursive_pay/F0C473D9BD583
```

in the function, I have redirected to google with redirect('http://www.google.com');for test but it does not seem to work.Any suggestions..

Comment: What do you want? Cron job won't redirect. How can a Terminal / shell redirect to a webpage?

Comment: The `php` command runs *local PHP files*, eg. `php cron.php foo`. The `curl/wget` command runs *remote PHP files (files though the webserver)*, eg. `curl http://www.domain.com?function=foo`.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php

Comment: Here is a complete explanation http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your php script can be invoked using an URL, you can lynx, or curl, or wget to setup your crontab.

```
*/5 * * * * lynx  http://localhost/domain/path/front_orders/recursive_pay/F0C473D9BD583.php
```

or

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl  http://localhost/domain/path/front_orders/recursive_pay/F0C473D9BD583
```

or

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q  http://localhost/domain/path/front_orders/recursive_pay/F0C473D9BD583
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of redirect('http://www.google.com'); trying using this:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

Comment: That's not related. `header()` does not work in cron job either.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl or wget if you want to just "ping" a url.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://localhost/domain/path/front_orders/recursive_pay/F0C473D9BD583
```

You can also use one of

```
/usr/bin/wget --spider http://localhost/... (if doing a HEAD call will do)
/usr/bin/curl http://localhost/... > dev/null 2>&1
```

If you use

```
/usr/bin/wget -q http://localhost/...
```

I think you will end up putting a copy of the result in whatever the 'current' directory is (differs based on which user's cron is running).

Comment: Note that is a capital O not a 0 in the wget -O example.