# How to make the hosting server run specific PHP code in timely manner?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I'm new to PHP and web applications. I have PHP code which collects info, from 5 huge XML files provided by other websites into a private MySQL database.

These XML files are updated and changed over time, and I want my database to be refreshed every day at 3:00 AM.

Can I make the hosting server run the PHP code by itsself? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hobo Sapiens says:

## Create a CRON Job

Put a shell script in one of these folders: /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.monthly or /etc/cron.weekly based on how often you want the script to run.

The shell script should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
php -q htdocs/file.php
```

For more specific timings take a look at [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job).

If you don't have SSH access to the server, you could also set up a cron job locally to ping the remote server using `wget --spider` or `curl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CRON jobs. Cron will automate your commands on a specific time.

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems.

[Read more about CRON jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Thank you, I would accept your answer, but Huey answer first.

Comment: thats fine, his answer is more detailed.