# PHP code works from URL but not in Linux crontab

Tags: php, cron, wget

I have some PHP code that pulls data from multiple sources and then dumps the results into a DB2 Database.  This PHP code works when you enter the URL for the PHP code.  Now trying to have it run twice a day using a crontab.  It doesn't seem to be working and the log file shows nothing. I'm using wget and thought it was timing out, so I have tried the following crontabs:

```
00 06 * * * wget http://website/phpcode.php >> /home/website/crontab.log
00 06 * * * wget -T0 http://website/phpcode.php >> /home/website/crontab.log
00 06 * * *  wget --timeoute=0 http://website/phpcode.php >> /home/website/crontab.log
```

When I try to run the *phpcode.php* from the Linux command line I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function db2_connect().

Any idea's how to get the code to work using the crontab with wget?

Comment: if you have access to the terminal, can you please try to invoke the command directly and check the output? `wget http://website/phpcode.php >> /home/website/crontab.log`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php on how to use `wget` to execute a remote script

Comment: there is two way to execute the php scripts from crontab one using wget and another using curl..  you can use anyone of them to execute php script

Comment: @sandeep_kosta Well there is a third way... `php`

Comment: And how should the second and third way help here?

Comment: @GrafiCode Studio, did that and it failed when checking for the certificate.  I added the --no-check-certificate and looks like it might have fixed it, but going to check again later to be sure. Thanks!