# CRON job doesn't run when I set a specific time

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I want to run a CRON command on certain days of the month at different times.

I have set up the CRON as indicated below:

40  8   5   12  6   php /home/username/public_html/path_to_php_script

*This is supposed to run at 8:40am on 5th December I presume but it never does.*

I noticed it only works when I use the common settings:

Example: */5    *   *   *   *   php /home/username/public_html/path_to_php_script

*This is supposed to run every five minutes*

I have read a lot of suggestions on StackOverflow and other articles including the [official documentation on cPanel.net](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs) all to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must not set the weekday. Just any (*) day.
40 8 5 12 * php /home/username/public_html/path_to_php_script

Comment: How can you tell if the php script run?

Comment: When I visit the link directly from my web browser. It works.

Comment: So, you shouldn't run the 'php' command, but the 'wget'. You may check this  at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php

Comment: I have also tried wget now.
It works when I use the common settings (Eg: Every 5 minutes etc) but when I specify a unique time, say, 6:00PM on Sundays, it doesn't run.

I tried wget, php and curl and they all showed similar results.

Comment: The timezone was the problem in my case. The CRON job actually works fine but the time on the server was 8 hours behind so I had to back date the time.

You could also change the time on the server if you had access to the WHM.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone was the problem in my case.
The CRON job actually works fine but the time on the server was 8 hours behind so I had to back date the time.

*You could also change the time on the server if you had access to the WHM.*