# How to suppress cron email feedback?

Tags: cron

I have a cron every two minutes (`*/2   *   *   *   *`) firing the following command...

```
wget "http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=my_key_stringimport_id=16&action=trigger"
```

Trouble is, it is emailing me every two minutes, and also creating copious tiny files on the server, one each time.

I have tried several things. I know there is plenty of info out there about suppressing email feedback from cron.

cPanel's Cron page, where my crons are set, makes clear: "If you do not want an email to be sent for an individual cron job, you can redirect the command’s output to /dev/null. For example: `mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1`"

But when I did it like this...

`wget -O "http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=my_key_stringimport_id=16&action=trigger" >/dev/null 2>&1`

... the cron stopped functioning.

(I believed an `-O` was necessarily to direct the output).

What is the proper way to formulate this?

Comment: You should add filename after `-O`. And this will not suppress mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick...

```
wget --quiet -O "http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=my_key_stringimport_id=16&action=trigger"
```

Ie. Add `--quiet`

Answer found [elsewhere on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33750094/1375163).

Bit confused how `--quiet` and `-O` co-exist.

Comment: There is no problem, `--quiet` and `-O`can coexist. But the command is wrong, after `-O` must be filename

Comment: Oh, yes, that was kind of a typo - I shouldn't have left in `>/dev/null 2>&1` after the file - I have edited my own answer. `http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=my_key_stringimport_id=16&action=trigger` is the file to execute.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress mails from cron you can add before your line in cron `MAILTO`

```
MAILTO=""
*/2 * * * * command
```